# Why are there similar Nuget package folders in .nuget\Packages directory?

Tags: nuget

Under `c:\Users\<USER NAME>\.nuget\packages\` directory, there are some folders looks similar, for example:

- System.IO.FileSystem.4.3.0
- system.io.filesystem  (and there are sub-folder "4.3.0" under it)

See attached figure. 
My question: why are there similar Nuget package folders in .nuget\Packages directory? Can I delete one of them?

[image: Nuget Package folder]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you used an old version of NuGet or Visual Studio on your machine, which used the old format. The other option is that you have a `nuget.config` that forces that solution packages folder to be your user profile's global packages folder. I really don't recommend this.

Maybe starting with NuGet 3.0 (Visual Studio 2015), NuGet uses the `tolower(packageid)\tolower(packageversion)\` folder structure. I'm too lazy to test old versions to validate that earlier versions used something different. Or maybe NuGet has always used the same format for the global packages folder, making the `packages.config` answer the only possibility. But I really think that lowercase normalisation was something that was added and didn't always exist.

projects that use `packages.config` have always used the unmodified `PackageId.PackageVersion` format in the **solution** packages folder. I believe it was deemed too risky as a breaking change that some customers depend on to change in the solution packages folder. So, if anyone had the misguided idea that they could save disk space by making all their solutions share the same packages folder by using the same one for all solutions, and the folder they used is the global packages folder, then the two different parts of NuGet which intentially use different folder naming conventions, will write to the same directory.

As long as you're not in the middle of a build, it's always safe to delete folders in any packages folder (global packages, as your question is about, or a solution packages folder). If a project needs a package that was deleted, NuGet will download it again, so if you have a download quota, or a slow internet connection, maybe be mindful. Otherwise you can be as liberal with deleting folders as you like. Just make sure to delete the entire folder. There's only one file NuGet looks for when restoring, so if you delete other files but leave that one, NuGet will think it's downloaded and extracted properly, but your machine will behave differently to other machines.